# How to resize UIButton without modifying its hit rectangle

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, uibutton

I have an `UIButton` with a `titleLabel` and a `backgroundImage`. I want to resize the button when it is in the highlighted state. This resize should affect the `titleLabel` and the `backgroundImage`, but I don't want to modify the hit area of the button.

Currently I am trying like this. It almost works, but it also affects the hit area:

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted
{
    if ( highlighted && !self.highlighted )
    {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleFactorOnTouch, scaleFactorOnTouch);
    }
    else if ( !highlighted && self.highlighted )
    {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
    }
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];
}
```

This causes that when you touch inside the button and drag outside its (extended by 100 pixels) hit area, there's this wiggle/tremor when you drag around the extended hit area edge. The wiggle is because the hitArea is changing constantly between the highlighted and non-highlighted state.

I also tried modifying the self.layer.transform property, but this also results in a change of the hit area.

If possible I would like to avoid setting a different backgroundImage for the highlighted state.

Comment: Why are your two conditions not opposites of one another? In the first, you set the transform of `self.titleLabel`. In the reverse, you reset the transform of `self`. Surely you don't mean that? You should be setting and resetting the transform of the same thing, yes?

Comment: Sorry, that was meant to read `self.transform` on both. I edited the question to reflect this. It showed `self.titleLabel.transform` because I was trying to resize the `titleLabel` and the `backgroundImage` manually, but I couldn't find a way to resize the `backgroundImage` (UIBUtton's backgroundImage just seems to take the button size).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've rightly observed, overriding `setHighlighted:` to change the transform of the button causes a kind of vicious loop. So don't do that! Instead, override `backgroundRectForBounds:`, like this:

```
- (CGRect)backgroundRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    CGRect result = [super backgroundRectForBounds:bounds];
    if (self.highlighted)
        result = CGRectInset(result, -3, -3);
    return result;
}
```

That enlarges the drawn size of the button during highlighting, but the enlarged drawing is only visible because `clipsToBounds` is NO. The bounds remain the same, and you can only touch within the bounds, so touch handling is unaffected.

That solves the background image part of the problem. If you really insist on changing the title size as well, I suppose you'll have to go on changing its transform. It would be less invasive to change the title's font (size) instead, though, I think - if that will work for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks! I think this will do. One last question before I accept the answer: the docs state that the `contentEdgeInsets` property should resize the button contents, so I thought this may be an alternative to achieve want I want. However, when I do `self.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(2,2,2,2)` my buttons remains the same. Why?